# Tailwind missing classes when on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, tailwind-css, css-purge

I have designed a beautiful page in tailwind on my Rails app and on my development server it looks great.  But when I push it to Heroku so many classes disappear.  Anything that uses the screen width tags (lg:w-1/4) doesn't work. I have a beautiful gradient in development but nothing on Heroku (bg-gradient-to-r from-green-300 via-blue-500 to-purple-600).  None of the code is dynamically called.  My tailwind config is using purge, but the file location is called out

```
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    content: [
      "./app/**/*.html.erb",
      "./app/**/*.js",
      "./app/**/*.css",
      "./app/**/*.scss",
      "./app/views/account/retreats/show.html.erb"
    ]
  },
```

I also feel like when I make changes to the tailwind config or the posts config, nothing I do matters to heroku after a fresh push.  I set purge: false and nothing different. Below are images of the differences.  When I compare the css files from production and development, the production is definitely missing the classes, but I cant figure out how to get heroku to rescan and see there are tailwind classes that need to be added.  Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]